# How do i get cypress element fixed when detached from the Dom?

Tags: javascript, npm, dom, cypress, cypress-file-upload

Cypress requires elements be attached in the DOM to interact with them.

The previous command that ran was:

> cy.get()

This DOM element likely became detached somewhere between the previous and current command.

Common situations why this happens:

- Your JS framework re-rendered asynchronously
- Your app code reacted to an event firing and removed the element

You typically need to re-query for the element or add 'guards' which delay Cypress from running new commands.

Here is the block of code I am trying to run.

```
  }),
    it('Add-Income', ()=> {
        cy.get('.add_btn').click()
        cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .input_container > input').type('45000')
        cy.get(':nth-child(2) > select').select('4')
        cy.get(':nth-child(3) > select').select('32')
        cy.get(':nth-child(4) > .input_container > input').invoke('removeAttr','type').type('12-12-1990{enter}')
        //cy.get('.transaction_btn > button').click()
        cy.get('.title > span').click({force: true})
        
    
    }),
    it('Add-Expenditure', ()=> {
        cy.get('.add_btn').click()
        cy.get('.overlay_card > :nth-child(4)').click()
        cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .input_container > input').type('45000')
        cy.get(':nth-child(2) > select').select('4')
        cy.get(':nth-child(3) > select').select('32')
        cy.get(':nth-child(4) > .input_container > input').invoke('removeAttr','type').type('12-12-1990{enter}')
        //cy.get('.transaction_btn > button').click()
    
    })
```

Comment: Can you attach the Cypress code you are getting this error with, as well as the HTML you are trying to run it on? As you've presented the question, the answer is in the error message.

Comment: What was the command that failed here?

Comment: Thanks for your response @jjhelguero.
I have added the code to the question.

Comment: You've got multiple `.get()` commands. Can you specify which one fails?